# For xterm.js version 3.6.0 how to make Ctrl+Shift+C key to Copy the selected text in the terminal

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, xtermjs

I am using xterm.js to emulate console using websockets.

My client is Google Chrome.
For xterm.js version 3.6.0 how to make Ctrl+Shift+C key to Copy the selected text in the terminal?
Whenever I press Ctrl+Shift+C, it opens the debug console of chrome.

Thanks in advance.
Regards.